# What is the purpose of variable_get in multilingual websites?

Tags: 7

I have installed a module and didn't find any possibility of changing the text strings appearing in the web. I went through the code and found the following:

```
variable_get('chosen_no_results_text', t('No results match'))
```

The string in the `t` function had been translated for me, but nothing happened.
As far as I understand, this introduces a variable with a fixed value, so I cannot have it translated for every language, and the variable is seen by all the users, irrespective of their prefered languages. Am I right? Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are right. Should be something like: t("!noresult", array('!noresult' => variable_get('chosen_no_results_text', 'No results match'))) otherwise only the default is translated

Comment: Yep, definitely a bug. Please report to the module in question's issue queue

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. I have modified the code and reported the issue, but not the patch because I still don't know how to process hacks. Thanks!